# How to change the length of the symbol of legend in matplotlib drawing?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

In the legend I drew, the dashed symbol is a little bit longer, as follows(in blue circle):
[image: a little longer symbeol]
How to reduce that extra bit?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant parameter is called `handlelength`:

[image]

```
plt.plot(range(5), range(5), label='lorem ipsum')
plt.legend(handlelength=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sure, but I guess the question was how to set the handlelength so that it only shows full dashes, not parts of a dash (other than by trial and error).

Comment: @stef Dash length is specified in display units, whereas the length of the handle is specified in fontsize units (according to the docs -- whatever that means). I am not sure a transformation between the two spaces is even possible because AFAIK text has to be rendered first before matplotlib knows its dimensions. So trial and error (of some form) is potentially all there is.